# Operator ' ' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm writing an Android application in Visual Studio, but stuck at this:

```
case Resource.String.strName:
                if(count == 0 && (editTxt2.Length != 0))
                {
                    //some statement
                    count++;
                }
                break;
```

at the line `editText2.Length` shows an error:

> Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'

No matter which operator I replace with, I get the same error. I've referred many posts but doesn't seems to be helpful.

Comment: What type is the "editTxt2", if it is actually an "Edit Text" are you sure you are not wanting the editTxt2.Text.Length?

Comment: It looks like `Length` isn't a property but a method, so you might want to try `editTxt2.Length()`.

Comment: What is `editTxt2` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Length isn't a **property** but a **method** of EditText. so it gives error **Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'**
just replace your code  with my ans it will sure help you my friend.

```
case Resource.String.strName:
                    if(count == 0 && editTxt2.Length() != 0)
                    {
                        //some statement
                        count++;
                    }
                    break;
```

Comment: Please do not post code only answers, add some description to your code.

Comment: @NileshRathod: Why next time? why not now with edit option? Anyway you are lucky to have an upvote even for this low quality post

Answer (score 0):

Length is a Method of the TextView, you are not calling the method.

To get the length of its text string you can either call the method, or get the text of your TextView and get the length of that.

1. `editTxt2.Length()`
2. `editTxt2.Text.Length`